# In a clustered environment, if there is items.xml change, is it enough to do Update Running System in one node and just clear cache the other nodes?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In a clustered environment, if there is items.xml change, is it enough to do Update Running System in one node and just clear cache the other nodes?

​Assume that I have Node1 and Node2. If I add an attribute in items.xml and build-and-deploy it to Node1 and Node2, is it enough for me to do Update Running System in Node1, and just Clear Cache Node2? Or, do I also need to do Update Running System in Node2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, its good to restart other nodes once you are done with an update running system. If zero downtime is not the case, then take downtime to make on node ready with an update system and then make other nodes ready.

**Another way:**
Take node1 out of the cluster, get it ready with all configuration, update system, etc. Add it back to the cluster and take all other nodes down. Do deployment on other remaining nodes and make them up. Here you do not need to update the running system or cache clear.

if downtime is really critical for the business, then refer [rolling update on the cluster](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8c455268866910149b25f7b53d1af3e1.html) to implement the proper solution.

Comment: I see. So, to summarize, Update Running System needs to be run in 1 node only.

Comment: and other nodes have to be restarted :)